# In monit setup got an error -> Sendmail: Authentication failed -- no supported authentication methods found

Tags: sendmail, monit

In /etc/monit/monitrc I added following block:

```
set mailserver 'smtp.gmail.com' port 587
            username 'xy@z.com'
            password 'whatever'
```

But it showing above error in log:

```
Sendmail: Authentication failed -- no supported authentication methods found
```

Comment: Not sure what to set value for 'using' parameter in above configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587
    username "xy@z.com" password "whatever"
    using tlsv1
```

**Note:** You need to enable the `IMAP` setting in your `Gmail` account to send mails via third party software. Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server) to know more.